# CSS font difference in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

[image]I have issues with font difference in Firefox/Chrome.
All the fonts seems bolder and bigger in Chrome than in Firefox, but I'd like to be like they are in Firefox.
I tried to add different properties, but seems nothing really works.
I'm using twitter bootstrap, so normalize.css is already included.
Any ideas, why such a difference?

I'm attaching photo, and here is the css used:

```
body{
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  color: #555555;
  font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857;
  font-weight:400;
  font-size-adjust: 0.5;
  font-weight:400;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.7px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; 
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); 
}

h3 {
  font-family:"Lato",sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  margin-bottom: 33px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 2.5em !important;
  line-height: 2 !important;
}
```

and the imported font:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Here is the link, and attached image of how I see it on my browswers.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sthAngels/kgnnnd6y/)
[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a dummy example using something like JSFiddle?

Comment: @NitinGarg I created a jsfiddle example and attached the image of how does it look on my browswers

Comment: @MrLister chrome version is 48, FF 44. I tried to use font-size-adjust (and is included in css), but it does work only on FF - but I like the font to be like on FF, for Chrome doesn't work (see my comments)

Comment: @AngelM. You're right, it doesn't. Well, MDN said it would work in v44. But apparently not. So to recap, if you remove all the `-webkit` properties and the `font-size-adjust` from the fiddle, the results are identical in Chromium and Mozilla.

Comment: @MrLister hm, not for me, it is the same difference :(

Comment: @MrLister sorry, now I saw, it makes a difference, thank you so much. If you'll create a real answer, I will accept it as the best one :)

Comment: there is still slight difference, but works fine. For someone who might have same issue -  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);  seems to help

Comment: @AngelM. Ehm, in what way does it help? I don't see any difference with or without it.

Comment: @MrLister if I add -webkit-transform-translate3d - fonts are pretty much of the same size, just small difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browsers don't all support the same font display features yet, unfortunately. If you only use the basics, the fonts will look the same across browsers.

```css
div {
  font: 14px/20px 'Arial', 'Liberation Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
```

But some features, such as `font-size-adjust`, will only have an effect in some browsers, not others.

```css
div {
  font: 14px/20px 'Arial', 'Liberation Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size-adjust: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
```

Same for things like `-webkit-text-stroke` and the like.

```css
div {
  font: 14px/20px 'Arial', 'Liberation Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.7px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; 
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
```

So in the end it's a trade-off between full cross-browser compatibility or getting the best possible result in each.

Comment: thanks again :) , even in my case I had to remove all additional settings to make it appear more or less similar